# How can the odd-even transposition sort algorithm be parallelized in an eficient way using PThreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, sorting, pthreads

I've recently started to study about parallel computing. I am currently reading about parallel sorting and searching algorithms. From the well known bubblesort algorithm, I found out about the Odd_Even_Transposition_Sort algorithm. For those who don`t already know, the last one can be parallelized more easily. I give two snippets of code for both algorithms below:

```
function bubbleSort(list) {
  sorted = false;
  while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
      if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
        swap(list[i], list[i + 1]);
        sorted = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
function oddEvenSort(list) {
  for (var k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i += 2) {
      if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
        swap(list[i], list[i + 1]);
      }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < list.length - 1; i += 2) {
      if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
        swap(list[i], list[i + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now to reach to my initial question, I don't understand how can the odd-even algorithm be parallelized efficiently. What I mean by efficiency? Using only as much threads as the number of cores your laptop has, or in any case, in a close range. From what I understand
the implementation given here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/odd-even-transposition-sort-brick-sort-using-pthreads/, wouldn't apply nicely to big arrays. In this example, there are only 8 elements and the number of threads (n + 1) / 2 = 4 is small. But for large arrays, for instance 500 elements wide which isn't even so big, the number of threads created I believe will create overhead. The problem, I think, comes from the fact that every comparison and potential swap in either the odd or even phase is put on a specific thread. Thus the more elements you have the more threads will be created. So how can the problem be parallelized for an array of let`s say 1000 elements using only 4 threads?

P.S.: Furthermore, I'm using Pthreads so any answer or piece of code written this way will help. Besides the answer, any refferrence to places(books, sites etc) where I can learn parallel computing better will be well-received.

Comment: Do you want fast sorting or parallelized bubble sorting?

Comment: Are they mutually exclusive? I want to implement odd even transposition sort using maximum 10 threads and on arrays at least 100 elements long. Hope it is possible lol. Thanks for the answer, I hope I'm clearer now.

Comment: _"Are they mutually exclusive?"_ - For anything but a few elements, yes, and if you have few elements, the overhead of starting/synchronizing threads will not be worth it.

Comment: You need to run X chunks of computation on Y cores, Y < X. Start Y threads. Have each thread run X/Y chunks one after another. I believe this is called "thread pool", look it up.

Comment: You're right. In the stated case this would mean, I think, that I have X elements in the array and I divide them in Y intervals. Then I have each thread run a fast serial sorting algorithm on each interval. But the main problem which I still don`t understand is how I make the threads communicate with each other. Indeed this is necessary because it is not sufficient to just sort the Y intervals in order to have an entirely sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with only `p` threads, the idea is to give blocks of size `n/p` for each thread, sort each block with a fast algorithm (like quick sort) and communicate last element of thread `i` with thread `i+1` and first element of thread `i+1` with thread `i` for the odd-even transposition (to combine the sort of each block).

I suggest you give a look at the explanation [here](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/MPIProgramming/build/html/oddEvenSort/oddEven.html) for deeper details and an implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reference! There might be indeed some useful explanation at the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying to make an implementation, I managed to reach to a solution of the problem. Thus, given an array of length N and P possible threads, the problem was how could I express the odd-even-transposition-sort algorithm in these terms knowing that the most basic and well known form of it is when the number of threads equals N.

As John Doe suggested, I split the N elements in P intervals, each of the P threads having its own thread_id. Just by knowing the id, N and P, I was able to find out in the code the dimension of each interval and the starting index of it. At first, I sorted with quicksort each of the P intervals providing a certain thread function for this task. Then, in another thread function I implemented the odd and even phases, but knowing that each interval has a length bigger than 1, I basically applied quicksort again on the neighbor intervals, in each thread. I also used a barrier after the even phase and after the odd phase to make sure the threads are synchronized.